# Чем сжимается информация в pdf?

Tags: pdf, php

Пытаюсь с помощью php прочитать поле author(title, keywords) у pdf файла. Использовал TCPDF, при этом файл парсится на объекты, но поля не являются чистыми а содержат примеси из разных символов - возможно ли, что это какое-то сжатие и если да то как от них избавится?

Парсится поле следующего вида, хотя по факту оно чистое:

`��<�?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1251'?><�stamps><�stamp></�stamp></�stamps>`

Comment: А кто-нибудь может подсказать шаблон регулярки, чтобы искало строку, которая, начиналась begin кончалась на end и содержало content?

Answer (score 2):

Информация в pdf может сжиматься двояко:

- сжатие данных (текст, картинки и т.п.),
- сжатие структуры файла.

Алгоритмы сжатия применяются разные, для текста это обычно Flate или LZW. Подробнее [здесь](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
 str_replace('�', '', $data); // xD
```

Comment: Нет это он в этой кодировке так выглядит а по факту там куча разных символов. Наверное я бы сам бы догадался, что делать если бы символы имели однородность. Вот вариант в cp1251:<br> юя<�?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1251'?><�stamps><�stamp><�department>яэяэяэяэяэяэ/department><�responsiblePerson>яэяэяэя

Comment: Подчеркиваю содержимое xml полностью отсутствует.

Comment: может такой pdf?..

Comment: Похоже, что ***они*** в начале каждого тэга. Может быть это какая-то длина (количество) ? Если все "лишние" символы таковы (в начале тэгов), то их можно распознать и удалить.

Comment: непонятный символ после угловой скобки возможно экранирование, потому, что он встречается повсюду, а остальные не очень понятны. В начале их можно распознать даже отбросить до <?xml, но что за ерунда в середине между тегами?

Comment: Почему в середине ? Смотрите (Ж - непонятный символ)

<Жstatmps> <Жstamp> </Жstamp>

В начале имени каждого **тэга** , а в закрывающем тэге после / но перед именем.

Т.е. надо удалять первый символ в имени тэга (или может быть вообще не удалять ? (ну, имя у тэга такое)).